# NameError: name 'l' is not defined while connecting Metamask in django

Tags: django, api, metamask

I'm now trying to connect my django page with Metamask for Ethereum(solidity) environment. All I want to do is connecting Metamask login function in my webpage. But I'm just a student and can't unserstand mechanisms well. I'm now just following instructions in https://django-web3-auth.readthedocs.io. in https://django-web3-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html page. I copied all the examples, but error NameError: name 'l' is not defined. What should I do?

```html
    File "C:\Users\000\Desktop\midpro2\hi\hiproject\settings.py", line 64, in <module>
    MIDDLEWARE = l
NameError: name 'l' is not defined
(myvenv)
```

**Settings.py**

```html
from django import get_version
from packaging import version

if version.parse(get_version()) < version.parse("1.10"):
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = l
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += ['django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware', ]
else:
    MIDDLEWARE = l

ROOT_URLCONF = 'hiproject.urls'
```

Comment: But `l` is indeed not defined. Why are you using it there? Nothing in the docs you link to says anything about doing this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually don't have any point of view how it works:(